# How to specify all factors the same colour and transparency in ggplot2, R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, line

I am plotting multiple regression lines separated by a factor `count`.

- I need all of the lines to be the same colour and transparency (eg. color = red, alpha = 0.5)
- Draw a mean for all the lines in the graph e.g. black, dashed line)

I tried adding the color + alpha parameters to the `geom_line()` but it produced a single line. Any suggestions?

[image]

#CODE to produce above graph

```
count <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3 1,2,3,1,2,3)
xcount <- rnorm(15,3,1)
ycount <- rnorm(15,5,1))

df <- data.frame(count, xcount, ycount)

ggplot(aes(x = xcount, y = ycount, color = factor(count)), data = df) +  
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", fill = NA) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) + 
  ylab("Y") + 
  xlab ("X") + theme(legend.position="none")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your group aesthetics out of the first ggplot declaration, then use in the first geom_smooth your grouping to create the 3 red lines. Add another geom_smooth without the grouping to create the line on all values (average)

```
ggplot(aes(x = xcount, y = ycount), data = df) +  
  geom_smooth(aes(group = factor(count)), method = "lm", fill = NA, color = "red") + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", fill = NA, color = "black", linetype = "longdash")
```

Note that in the above `alpha = 0.5` is removed as it is **not** supported in `geom_smooth`, to achieve that as well you can use `stat_smooth` instead like this so your red lines will have the desired transparency.

```
ggplot(aes(x = xcount, y = ycount), data = df) +  
  stat_smooth(aes(group = factor(count)), geom = "line", method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "red", alpha=0.5) +
  stat_smooth(geom = "line", method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "black", linetype = "longdash")
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks for the alpha calrification

Answer (score 1):

For the single color and alpha, just pull the dimension you're specifying outside of the `aes()` call. Anything outside of `aes` will be applied to every line. The trick is also having the groups specified  to avoid getting a single line.

```
ggplot(aes(x = xcount, y = ycount, group = factor(count), data = df) +  
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", fill = NA, color = 'red', alpha = 0.5)
```

As for an average line, the easiest way to do that is pre-compute the mean right before your plot. Assuming you place the mean in a variable called `mu`, you would just need to add the following:

```
+ geom_hline(yintercept = mu, linetype = 'longdash')
```

Comment: Thank you. The alpha is not working though...

Comment: What behavior are you seeing with the alpha? If I recall correctly, it should affect the bands around the line and not the lines themselves.

Comment: alpha is not supported in geom_smooth, see my example that I updated with using stat_smooth instead.